# How to use Multiple versions of the same connector in a Mule project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, connector

I need to use 2 versions of the connector within a single Mule application project.

When I import the connector from exchange it overwrites or updates the existing version of connector.

Instead I need to retain the previous version of the connector as well as use the latest version of connector.

I tried manually editing the pom file and adding both versions :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>dh83604f-7390-354a-2aca-67ctycbbcbgn</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-plugin-deck-ply</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2021070401</version>
  <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>dh83604f-7390-354a-2aca-67ctycbbcbgn</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-plugin-deck-ply</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2021081103</version>
  <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
</dependency>
```

In the mule palette it shows both connectors with different versions.

But when I build the project, the build fails as it not recognizing the dependency.

So how can I use 2 version of the same dependency in a single project ?

Comment: Why do you need two versions of a connector in the same Mule application? Doesn't the newest one work?

Answer (score 1):

A Mule application can not use more than one version of a dependency in the same project. It will use the newest version only. I would question the need for trying to use both versions. It seems that if the newest version misses a feature then it should be really a different connector. If it is a bug fix that is missed, then it should be resolved. It doesn't really make sense to try to use two versions.